# Display Timeline/Linear data in Flot

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flot, timeline

Does anyone know how to get flot to display a type of 'timeline'?

E.g.

```
Y:
Person1| -----     -------
Person2|    -------   -------
Person3| -- -----    ----
Person4|       -------
        _____________________
X:      Jan  Feb  March  April
```

I'm not sure how to display the labels on the y axis and show the data linear

**Solution so far :)**

$(document).ready(function(){

```
var d1 = [[(new Date("01/01/2009")).getTime(), 5], [(new Date("10/01/2009")).getTime(), 5]];

var placeholder = $("#placeholder");

// plot it
var plot = $.plot(placeholder, [d1], {xaxis:{mode:"time", timeformat:"%b.%y"}});
```

});

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have solved the issue?

Comment: Can you show the image your chart and code so I can get it because I have the same query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the answer. Use the configuration 'ticks'.

**Solution:**

```
//american dates
    var d1 = [[(new Date("01/01/2009")).getTime(), 1], [(new Date("01/10/2009")).getTime(), 1]];
    var d2 = [[(new Date("05/05/2009")).getTime(), 2], [(new Date("06/23/2009")).getTime(), 2]];
    var d3 = [[(new Date("03/10/2009")).getTime(), 3], [(new Date("03/15/2009")).getTime(), 3]];
    //var d1 = [[0, 5], [5, 5], null, [5, 10], [15, 10]];
    var placeholder = $("#placeholder");

    // plot it
    var plot = $.plot(placeholder, [d1,d2,d3], {
        xaxis:{mode:"time", timeformat:"%b.%y"},
        yaxis:{ticks:[[1, "Apple"], [2, "Microsoft"], [3, "Dell"]]}
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

View the source of http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/basic.html
pay particular attention to the comment `// a null signifies separate line segments`
I think that should get you where you want to be.

Comment: Thanks for that, yea I saw that... but I dont seem to get the same result if the xaxis is time! as I'm not sure how to set the yaxis to something other like 'persons' for each dataset.